# Перенос проектов с одного Denwer'а на другой

Tags: php, denwer

Что необходимо, что бы перенести проекты с одного денвера на другой? Кроме как скопировать код из папки home и бд из `usr\local\mysql-5.5\data`?

Нужно что-то переносить дополнительно?

Comment: С одного денвера на другой денвер? :)

Comment: @romeo что не понятно в вопросе?

Comment: Не, не понятно.

Comment: @afortstr Кроме кода и БД, нужно ещё перенести конфиги Apache (httpd.conf), конфиг PHP (php.ini). Только убедитесь, что версии Apache и PHP совпадают у обоих Denwer'ов.

Comment: @MAXOPKA если не совпадают?

Comment: @afortstr, Denwer умер. Котеров и Co забили на него уже года 3-4 назад. Предлагаю альтернативы: [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/easyphp-devserver.php),...

Comment: @afortstr Если не совпадают, то перенесите настройки Apache, который касаются настройки хостов и директорий. А в PHP - список подключенных модулей.

Comment: @MAXOPKA спасибо

Comment: @romeo у меня задача перенести с денвера на wampserver, а заодно хотел знать как правильно с денвера на денвера переносить проекты

Comment: @afortstr При переносе БД, лучше не файлы переносить, а сделать дамп. Для MySQL: [`mysqldump`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/105954/), PostgreSQL: [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/backup-dump.html). А то, знаете ли InnoDB  и всё такое.

Comment: @romeo спасибо.